# How to sign in using data from WebSecurity tables?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, hash, authentication, passwords

I want to sign users in with the standard WebSecurity tables; but in another language.

For example I have this ASP MVC website. I'm making an app using PHP now that has access to the same database, and I need to know how microsoft's password strategies work.

Here's an example of a table: http://gyazo.com/e55d76186472b17fe8f25481a3a3e1c9

I would guess it's just hash_password=  hash(password . salt)

But which hashing does it use, etc etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, reflector tells me that they use `Crypto.HashPassword` which looks like:

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] buffer2;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    using (System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
    {
        salt = bytes.Salt;
        buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```